# Insert multiple row to table in firebird

Tags: firebird

I added one thousand rows to one of my tables while working on SQL Server, I used something like:

```sql
DECLARE @cnt2 INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt2 < 1000
BEGIN
    insert into [MyDB].[dbo].[Table] (ID, LastName, FirstName, StreetAddress, City, ZipCode, PhoneNumber, Email, EnteringDate, GroupID)
    values (00+ Convert(varchar(5), @cnt2), 'StudentLastName-' + Convert(varchar(5), @cnt2), 'FirstName', 'Street',  'City', 'xx-xxx', '500-000-000', 'email@student.xyz', GETDATE(), 0, 1)
    SET @cnt2 = @cnt2 + 1;
END;
```

And it works correctly, but I must have similar code to insert values during using Firebird.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: pgadmin is for PostgreSQL, not for Firebird. Are you sure you're using Firebird?

Comment: I know, I know! Maybe description is not clear enough. I need to have two codes. One for PostgreSQL (pgadmin) and one for Firebird (Firebird SQL Server). Thank you for code to Firebird. –

Comment: It is usually better to focus on one target database or language when asking questions. I have removed the references to PostgreSQL, and suggest that you ask a new question. I would recommend tagging that question with postgresql, not pgadmin.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent for this in Firebird would require an [execute block](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-execblock) (an anonymous procedure), or a stored procedure.

The code would be something like:

```sql
execute block as
declare variable cnt2 integer = 0;
begin
    while (cnt2 < 1000) do
    begin
        insert into Table (ID, LastName, FirstName, StreetAddress, City, ZipCode, PhoneNumber, Email, EnteringDate, GroupID)
        values ('00' || :cnt2, 'StudentLastName-' || :cnt2, 'FirstName', 'Street',  'City', 'xx-xxx', '500-000-000', 'email@student.xyz', CURRENT_DATE, 0, 1);
        cnt2 = cnt2 + 1;
    end
end
```

Comment: ....or a oneliner using GENERATOR :-) `insert from select ... where GEN_ID( ..., 0) <= Last_Value`

Comment: @Arioch'The I'd suggest posting an answer, as I'm not sure how you want to do that without having a table that can produce 1000 rows, not to mention the possibility of interference from concurrent use of the same generator. I think I know what you mean, but that would be a solution that relies on the cursor instability problem that should be solved in Firebird 4.

Comment: Recursive CTE can be used to produce sequence, but making it work for over 1024 rows is overly complicated, so this answer is the best option.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i think you know what i think, but FB4 is not released and even FB3 is not mentioned in this question, so that should work. Won't do an answer though for using a DB-global object generator is for a local task of one query is dirty hack.